# initialValue attribute of @TableGenerator shows issue in Hibernate but not in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, generator

```
package com.sb.firstjpaexample.pojo;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.TableGenerator;

  @Entity
  @Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
  public class Employee {

@Id
@TableGenerator(name = "TABLE_GEN", table = "SEQUENCE_TABLE", pkColumnName = "SEQ_NAME", valueColumnName = "SEQ_COUNT", pkColumnValue = "EMP_SEQ", initialValue = 1001, allocationSize = 5)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "TABLE_GEN")
private int employeeId;

@Column
private String employeeName;
@Column
private String designation;
@Column
private double salary;

public int getEmployeeId() {
    return employeeId;
}

public void setEmployeeId(int employeeId) {
    this.employeeId = employeeId;
}

public String getEmployeeName() {
    return employeeName;
}

public void setEmployeeName(String employeeName) {
    this.employeeName = employeeName;
}

public String getDesignation() {
    return designation;
}

public void setDesignation(String designation) {
    this.designation = designation;
}

public double getSalary() {
    return salary;
}

public void setSalary(double salary) {
    this.salary = salary;
}
```

}

"This POJO takes initial value as 1001 in JPA but takes 1 as initial value in Hibernate"
One more doubt how to set increment step here using annotations
In JPA it shows no problem but problem in increment when i use increment strategies

Please help me and thanks in advance

Comment: Please some one give me solution for that

Comment: I have raise same issue in hibernate jira forum

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just had the same problem. It is the mis-matched with hibernate old generator and JPA.

You need to add this to your config

see hibernate doc : http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/ch01.html#d0e200

Comment: Thank you. You saved my day! For anyone having problem with sequence-generators not working (for instance not respecting initial values set) just do what Stephane said.