# @GeneratedValue for non-identity column in HSQLDB

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hsqldb

I am using JPA/Hibernate trying to insert an entity in HSQLDB with a column annotated as:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Generated(value = GenerationTime.INSERT)
@Column(name = "u_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
```

In SQL Server a uuid is generated and everything works fine. In HSQLDB a null value is inserted in the database. How do I get it to generate an id? The column is not a key column.

Thanks
Markus

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
 <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="true"/>
```

[Why sometimes it doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16836058/initialvalue-attribute-of-tablegenerator-shows-issue-in-hibernate-but-not-in-jp)

It is the mis-matched with hibernate old generator and JPA.